# Error on push of sitecore CLI : Executed action can only be performed by Sitecore Administrators

Tags: graphql, sitecore-cli, sxa-cli

I have sitecore instance on virtual machine, and I am trying to pull and push with my admin credentials only.

But still receiving following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with update the config `Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Serialization.config` by updating the `requireAuthentication` node to false.

```
<security type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Security.GraphQLSecurity, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL">
          <requireAuthentication>false</requireAuthentication>
          <requireApiKey>false</requireApiKey>
</security>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This configuration should not be recommended in any publicly available environments as it opens up your GraphQL Management services to any bad actors.