# ERROR [Sitecore Identity] 'http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer' claim is missing. | Sitecore 10.2

Tags: sitecore-cli

When I am trying to use clientid and password for pushing and pulling from sitecore environment with Sitecore CLI.

I am getting following error in logs:

> ERROR [Sitecore Identity]
> 'http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer' claim is
> missing.

I already tried adding the originalissuer in claims

In the powershell, I am getting following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the CLI User is not getting created in the CMS as a User like the other environments.

Check `requiresUniqueEmail` is `false` in the `web.config`, and all files are the same across environments (except for values that should be different like the URLs of the ID Service, CMS, and CliServerClient).

Sitecore Security Hardening to create a strong Password Policy [(Enforce a strong password policy (sitecore.com)](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/enforce-a-strong-password-policy.html), the Regex of the `passwordStrengthRegularExpression` setting was the issue.

Remove the `passwordStrengthRegularExpression` as per Microsoft.

> The random password will meet the criteria established by the
> `MinRequiredPasswordLength` and `MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters`.

**Credit:** https://thebitsthatbyte.com/sitecore-cli-non-interactive-user-not-created/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks sumit, I tried it but no luck.

Comment: Try out other points as i answered and see if that resolve the issue. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35253/sitecore-cli-not-authorized-to-perform-the-task-you-are-attempting-no-sitecore/35254#35254

Comment: nope, I updated the description with error in powershell.

Comment: I don't see Claim missing error in the screenshot. Is it resolved?

Comment: claim missing is in logs but in powershell, it shows like this

Comment: Does this help? You faced such the same issue earlier and it got resolved with this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35034/error-on-push-of-sitecore-cli-executed-action-can-only-be-performed-by-sitecor